# Missing URI template variable for method parameter of type String

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, crud

This is what my REST controller looks like

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/type/{eventtype}/events")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getEventsSpecificType(@PathVariable String eventType) throws InvalidRequestException {
    return ResponseRestBuilder.createSuccessResponse(
            portEventRepository.
                    findByEventTypeOrderByTimestampAsc
                            (eventType));
}
```

Calling it from Postman with the following URI

```
http://localhost:8181/type/default/events
```

gets me this error

```
{
"timestamp": 1518605163296,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingPathVariableException",
"message": "Missing URI template variable 'eventType' for method parameter of type String",
"path": "/type/default/events"
```

}

What am I missing? Isn't the String variable properly mapped?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must give the name of the path variable, the name of the method parameter doesn't matter. And the name of the path variable must match **exactly** the name used in your Path (eventtype).

```
getEventsSpecificType(@PathVariable("eventtype") String eventType)
```

If you don't specify the @PathVariable, the name must match exactly the name used in the path. So change the eventType method parameter to eventtype.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got same Issue and Resolved by **Changing Name of Path variable Like

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/type/{eventType}/events")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> getEventsSpecificType(@PathVariable String eventType) throws InvalidRequestException {
```